# Maps v2 my-location layer Style

Tags: android-maps-v2

How to change the basic blue color of my-location layer. 
And can I replace it with marker. Or i have to buld custom Tile.

And can i remove only pin with the radius and keep che locate-me tile

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any style cusomization. And the marker cannot be replaced.

I did a custom tile, and a custom getCurrentLocation function.

Here is my code:

First you need tile for the Locate me button in the top right corner. I add it to the Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/tabs_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.bucons.savetime.MyMapFragment" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myLocationButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_mylocation"
        android:background="@drawable/map_tile_bg" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Needed resources are @drawable/ic_menu_mylocation 
You can get it from:    **https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzGos46YSzYfWkRYS2ZMNmdZREk/edit**

And for Background: @drawable/map_tile_bg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
     <item android:state_pressed="true">
         <shape android:shape="rectangle">
             <stroke 
                 android:width="1px"
                 android:color="@color/map_tile_bg_stroke_pressed"/>
             <solid android:color="@color/map_tile_bg_solid_pressed"/>
             <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
         </shape>
     </item>
       <item>
         <shape android:shape="rectangle">
             <stroke 
                 android:width="1px" 
                 android:color="@color/map_tile_bg_stroke"/>
             <solid android:color="@color/map_tile_bg_solid"/>
             <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
         </shape>
       </item>
</selector>
```

Color resourser are:

```
<color name="map_tile_bg_solid">#aaffffff</color>
<color name="map_tile_bg_stroke">#ffcccccc</color>
<color name="map_tile_bg_solid_pressed">#aaFF9933</color>
<color name="map_tile_bg_stroke_pressed">#ffcccccc</color>
```

And here is my fragment:

```
public class MyMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    //Current location Marker
    private Marker myLocationMarker;

    GoogleMap map = null;

    public MyMapFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        getCurrentLocation();
    }  

    //set the map and set the tile for locate me button
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (map == null) {
            map = getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (map != null) {
                //Top right button for go to location
                ImageButton locateMeTile = (ImageButton) getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.myLocationButton);
                locateMeTile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        getCurrentLocation();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    //retrieve the current position. Only once
    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSherlockActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria crit = new Criteria();
        String towers = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, false);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(towers);

        Double glat = null;
        Double glon = null;
        if(location != null){

            glat = location.getLatitude();
            glon = location.getLongitude();

        }

        CameraPosition pos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(glat, glon))
        .zoom(10)
        .build();     

        if(pos != null) {
            currLocationChange(pos.target);
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(pos));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), R.string.main_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    //Add pin to the current Location or move existing
    private void currLocationChange(LatLng loc) {
        if(myLocationMarker != null) {
            myLocationMarker.setPosition(new LatLng(loc.latitude,loc.longitude));
        } else {
            myLocationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(loc.latitude,loc.longitude)));
        }
    }
}
```